# Lvalue reference initialization from brace-enclosed initializer list fails to compile

Tags: c++, reference, lvalue

I have very simple program:

```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
     string var {"test"};
     string &lr {var};

     cout << var << "\n";
     cout << lr << "\n";
  }
```

Compile it as follows:

```
g++ ./test.cpp -g3 -std=c++0x
./test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./test.cpp:9:19: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’
```

But if I change initialization of `lr` to `string &lr = var;`, it compiles and works.

g++ version is 4.6.3

Actually the code above is a slightly modified example from "The C++ Programming Language", 2013 by Stroustrup, section 7.7.2, and I see no reason for it not to work. Have I missed something?

**UPD:** here is the original example from the book:

```
string var {"Cambridge"};
string f();

string& r1 {var};         // lvalue reference, bind r1 to var (an lvalue)
string& r2 {f()};         // lvalue reference, error : f() is an rvalue
string& r3 {"Princeton"}; // lvalue reference, error : cannot bind to temporary
```

So the line `string& r1 {var};` perfectly corresponds to mine `string &lr {var};`, and the source `string` is initialized in quite the same way.

Comment: How does it differ from the original example in the book?

Comment: gcc 4.6 is quite old; notice it still has `c++0x` instead of `c++11`. You might want to try with a more recent version.

Comment: @Angew, ok, well, I still use what Linux Mint 13 LTS offers, still have no time to bother upgrading. I'll try to find the way to test newer version, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the compiler. gcc 4.6.3 is quite old; notice it still has to use `c++0x` instead of `c++11`. With a more recent version (4.9.2 in particular), the code [compiles and runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f18119d3dae20e2c) just fine.